# Python wont write text file

Tags: python, text-files

I write:

```
f = open("Textfile.txt","w")
f.write("This is a text file")
f.close()
```

But when i open the text file nothing has been written, does anybody know why?

Comment: Try `f.flush()` before `.close()`.

Comment: I tried, it works for me

Comment: Something is very wrong if you need to call `flush`; `close` should flush any unwritten data before closing.

Comment: Try `print(os.path.abspath(f.name))` to see if you look to the good file

Comment: What you have should work, but what happens if you use the recommended `with` statement: `with open("Textfile.txt", "w") as f: f.write("This is a text file\n")`? (You can also try `print("this is a text file", file=f)`. `print` will add a newline implicitly; with `write` you need to specify it explicitly.)

Comment: it still doesn't work, would there be anything else stopping this from working?

Comment: Probably you're looking in the wrong place for the file.

Comment: Add `print(os.getcwd())` before your code so that you will see where Python is actually creating your output file.

Comment: adding  print(os.getcwd()) has worked and it has actually saved in the location, is there a way of changing the save location since its in such a strange place?

Answer (score 0):

using it in a with statement should handle the closing of the file for you.  Does this solve the problem?

```
 with open('Textfile.txt','w') as f:
        f.write('This is a text file')
```

Comment: The first code should work, so I don't think changing the code is a good idea

Comment: The first code *should* work, but you should also be using a `with` statement where possible to ensure the file is properly closed even in the event of an exception that prevents the explicit call to `f.close` from being reached.

Answer (score 0):

To save a file at the desired location use the full path.

```
with open('/home/me/project/testfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write('content')
```

If you want to save your file in the same directory as your script you can use `__file__`.

```
import os.path
path_of_script = os.path.dirname(__file__)
with open(os.path.join(path_of_script, 'testfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write('content')
```